# how to use insert statement with where clause from diff table in oracle without using plsql

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sql-insert

I want to insert like below

```
If 
   select *from class where student_name='A' ;
then
   Insert into student (Studnetname varchar2,rollno integer) values('A',1);
```

without using PL/SQL

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't that be as simple as

```
insert into student (studentname, rollno)
select student_name, rollno
from class
where student_name = 'A'
  and rollno = 1;
```

If such a student (whose values satisfy the `WHERE` clause) exists, a row will be inserted. Otherwise, nothing will happen.

Comment: Please help to answer for  updated one , I want direct insert statement without select

Comment: @MuditB - The subject and text of the question both say "without PL/SQL".  This answer does not use PL/SQL.  If you are really concerned about the form of the `insert` statement, it would make sense to use PL/SQL.  Can you explain why you can't use PL/SQL?  Potentially, you could use a `SQL*Plus` script with a number of variables but that isn't a particularly common solution.

Answer (score 0):

> I want direct insert statement without select

The closest you will get to meeting this requirement is something like this:

```
Insert into student (Studnetname, rollno) 
select 'A',1
from dual 
where exists (select null from class where student_name = 'A' )
;
```

This will insert one row into STUDENT if there is at least one record in CLASS matching the given criterion.